# How to send in Android a variable from 1 class to another

Tags: java, android

I have 3 Activities(First,Second,Third) and want to send a variable from First Activity to the Third and use it with a value,which I gave it in First Activity. I found information only how to send variables from 1st to 2nd Activity.

Comment: you want to send data from First to third activity , and are you navigating to third activity from first to second and from second to third and do you want some result from Third activity back in first activity

Answer (score 1):

StartActivityForResult

First activity can call third with the variable you want. Once third activity is finished it will send the
Results back to first activity.

Just search for Android startactivityforresult

Comment: What I should change?

FirstActivity{ 
String user = eUser.getText().toString();
Intent i = new Intent("package.SECOND");
startActivity(i); }
Second{
Intent i = new Intent("package.THIRD");
startActivity(i); {
Third{
  //here I want to get "user" from 1st Class
}